How do you force the MSVC compilier to use the multi byte character set when using QT Creator and CMake
I am currently converting an ancient MFC application into a QT one.
This old MFC application uses libraries that use multibyte character sets but whenever I try to include them in the new QT application the application instantly crashes. I know its a problem with the multibyte characters as when I create a dummy library that uses Unicode character sets it works fine but once I switch to multibyte it crashes again.
I have tried running these commands in my CMake file to force the MSVC compilier to use multi byte but the application still crashes.
qt6_disable_unicode_defines(appName)
target_compile_definitions(appName PUBLIC _MBCS)
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} /D _MBCS")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /D _MBCS")

I have also looked at this post Setting Character set for MSVC compiler from another IDE (Qt Creator)  which is having the same problem but all the answers assume you are using the outdate QMake with QT Creator where as I'm using CMake.
